# Qt: force UI update in the main thread

Tags: qt, user-interface, updates

I'm writing an image viewer and I want to pre-load the next image after displaying the current one.

The problem is now: When I display an image (e.g. by applying a `QPixmap` to a `QLabel`) and load the next image in the same Qt-method-call (e.g. in the same function) the image will be displayed after the pre-loading. So I still have the time gap..

I could switch to a threaded solution but this would introduce a lot of more problems.

So my question for now is: Can I force Qt to `update()`/`redraw()` the UI in the current call stack or will I have to find a way to do the pre-loading in another "metacall"?

Comment: You could register a custom [`Qevent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#registerEventType) and use that to trigger pre-loading of the next image (assuming you *really* don't want to use threads).

Comment: That's a good idea but I doubt that works. I've tried a `QMetaObject.invokeMethod` (which is basicly the same as firing an event) but since I'm in the main event loop already the update will still be done *after* my invoked function has been called..

Comment: Good time to learn threading.

Comment: Note that `QMetaObject.invokeMethod` is only guaranteed to use the event loop if you specify [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) as the connection type.  Is that what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to solve the problem in the following way (without dealing with threads):

```
void setCurrentImage()
{
    [..]
    label->setPixmap(pixmap);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(preloadNextImage()));
    [..]
}

// A slot.
void preloadNextImage()
{
    // Do preload.
}
```